# How to store each user input into array?

Tags: c++, c++11

I used a do while loop to ask user to enter integer as long as its not 0 or it will exit the program. I'm stuck on how to store every user input into the dynamically allocated array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
  int *A;
  A= new int();
  int n;
  do{
    cout<<"Enter integer: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<< *A + n << endl;

    
  }while(n!=0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: use std::vector

Comment: @pm100 we haven't learned about vectors yet

Comment: Have you learnt how to use [`std::realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc)? I am not recommending that you use that function, I am just asking, in order to try to guess how you are supposed to solve the problem.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel not yet

Comment: @mluong then what HAVE you learned so far?

Comment: Have you learnt about linked lists? Maybe you are supposed to use them, instead of using a "dynamic array"? Or would a fixed-length array be sufficient, with a limit of, let's say, 40 elements?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Arrays and pointers

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Linked lists not yet  but later on. The question was Write a main function in which a user is prompted repeatedly to an arbitrary number of
positive integers n, greater than 0, one after another. The prompt works as long as the user does not
enter 0. If 0 is entered, then the prompt ends. While the prompt is ongoing, each entered integer (except
0) is stored in an array, called A.

Comment: @mluong: That sounds to me that `A` is supposed to be a fixed-length array, not a "dynamic array". Although the task description says "arbitrary number of positive integers", this does not exclude an upper bound.

Comment: vectors are simple to use and by far the better way. Earn extra credit, and self confidence by teaching yourself. That is the one true skill to come from a CS class (learning to use a debugger would be too, but sadly no CS classes seem to teach that)

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating a single `int`, not an array of `int`s.

Also, even if you were allocating an array, a statement like `*A + n` does not add `n` to the array.  It dereferences `A` to access the *value* of the 1st `int` in the array, and then adds `n` to that *value*.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int *A = nullptr;
  int count = 0, n;

  do{
    cout << "Enter integer: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0) break;
    
    int *newA = new int[count+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) newA[i] = A[i];
    newA[count] = n;
    delete[] A;
    A = newA;
    ++count;

    cout << A[count-1] << endl;
  }
  while (true);

  delete[] A;

  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, try to avoid reallocating the array on every input, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int *A = new int[5];
  int count = 0, cap = 5, n;

  do{
    cout << "Enter integer: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0) break;
    
    if (count == cap)
    {
        int newCap = cap * 1.5;
        int *newA = new int[newCap];
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) newA[i] = A[i];
        delete[] A;
        A = newA;
        cap = newCap;
    }

    A[count] = n;
    ++count;

    cout << A[count-1] << endl;
  }
  while (true);

  delete[] A;

  return 0;
}
```

That being said, a better option is to use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which will handle the dynamic memory for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> A;
  int n;
  do{
    cout << "Enter integer: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0) break;
    A.push_back(n);
    cout << A.back() << endl;
  }
  while (true);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: and lets encourage not using `using namespace std;` from day one.